# for loop string comparator will only iterate once

Tags: python, list, for-loop

i'm new to python. this code snippet takes a list of length 25 (dev_info_lines) and finds parts of strings and assigns them to properties of the dev object. it seems very straightforward. however the for loop will only iterate once even though there are 25 lines in the list. why?

i'm sure i'm missing something obvious, i started coding in python just yesterday.

EDIT: Fixed my code with the error found by the community, maybe this operational function will be useful to someone else. (In case you're wondering, my return dev line was indented inside the for loop, ending it and the function prematurely. A rookie mistake for sure!) Thanks everyone!

EDIT2: Finished this project, anyone interested in a link to the full script can find it [here](http://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/python-script-to-monitor-drive-temps.22794/#post-144657). It sends email reports of drive temperatures and SMART test results in FreeNAS.

```
def SortInfo(device_id):
    dev_info_lines = (a command that returns a list of 25 lines about hard drive SMART info)
    bEnteredInfoSection = False
    i=0
    for line in dev_info_lines:
        i=i+1
        if ( not bEnteredInfoSection ):
            TheFirstField = string.split(line," ",2)
            if ( "information section" in line.lower() ):
                bEnteredInfoSection = True
        else:
            field = string.split(line,":",1)
            if (field[0].lower() == "model family" ):
                dev.family = field[1].strip()
            elif (field[0].lower() == "device model" ):
                dev.model = field[1].strip()
            elif (field[0].lower() == "serial number" ):
                dev.serial = field[1].strip()
            elif (field[0].lower() == "firmware version" ):
                dev.firmware_version = field[1].strip()
            elif (field[0].lower() == "user capacity" ):
                dev.capacity = field[1].strip()
            elif (field[0].lower() == "sector sizes" ):
                dev.sector_sizes = field[1].strip()
            elif (field[0].lower() == "rotation rate" ):
                dev.rotation_rate = field[1].strip()
            elif (field[0].lower() == "device is" ):
                dev.device_is = field[1].strip()
            elif (field[0].lower() == "ata version is" ):
                dev.ata_version = field[1].strip()
            elif (field[0].lower() == "sata version is" ):
                dev.sata_version = field[1].strip()
            elif (field[0].lower() == "smart support is" ):
                temp = string.split(field[1].strip()," ",1)
                strTemp = temp[0].strip().lower()
                if (strTemp == "available" ):
                    dev.smart_support_available = True
                elif (strTemp == "unavailable" ):
                    dev.smart_support_available = False
                elif (strTemp == "enabled" ):
                    dev.smart_support_enabled = True
                elif (strTemp == "disabled" ):
                    dev.smart_support_enabled = False
    return dev
```

Comment: `for line in dev_info_lines.split('\n')`

Comment: `dev_info_lines` may be a single long string comprising of the entire 25 lines. You may have to split it accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your quick answers! dev_info_lines is already split into a list of lines. meaning len(dev_info_lines)=25. i have edited post to make that more clear. any other ideas?

Comment: you have iteraionnumber=0 and then iterationnumber=iterationnumber+1 (notice the t lacking in the first one).

Comment: that's actually a typo in the post that is not present in the code. editing to match what i have in the code.

Comment: someone noticed that the return dev was in the for loop. that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is very friendly to debug with print statements, especially for text processing.

You need to :

- print dev_info_lines
- print len(dev_info_lines) just before the loop (to make sure it is what you think it is)
- print line at the beginning of the iteration

The answer of why it's not iterating will be immediately apparent, and you will have your next concrete question for us :)

Comment: thanks. but i already did this. the dev_info_line is a list of 25 strings but the for loop never iterates more than once and an hour more of experimenting has not made it obvious why. what could cause the for loop to end early?

Comment: What is "line" at the beginning of the first iteration?

Comment: I've just noticed that the code you have pasted is definitely not the code you are running.  Not only have you commented out the way dev_info_lines is generated (fair enough) but your declaration of SortInfo can't possibly work.    This makes it hard to help you debug: for all we know, you may have the indentation completely wrong.  If your python file were all indented differently, you might not have a loop at all..   You need to post _exactly_ what you are running to get good help here.   You need to strip down what you are running until it still has the problem _and_ can be pasted directly.

Comment: my best guess is that in his code, `return dev` is indented inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Or the body of the loop is not indented in the loop.   The def line is missing a colon, so this is not the code he is running.

Comment: GreenAsJade yes, i see your point. i was trying to make the code more readable (no one wants to read my whole function, i thought) but yes i see now that it has the potential to create more problems and that's not worth everyone's time.

AdamSmith yep, that was it! i looked at that several times very briefly thinking thinking "yeah that needs to be there to close the loop" when python uses indentation to define the end of statements. that kept not clicking, but it's definitely clicked this time!

Comment: It sounds like your problem is solved.  You should mark an answer as "accepted" (by clicking the big tick) to indicate that this is the case.  You should upvote answers that contributed to helping you solve the problem.  If you don't do that, people will be less inclined to help you next time. In order to persuade people not to vote down your question, you should fix up the code you posted so that it does not contain blatant errors.

Comment: Done and done. This whole community-forum method of crowdsourced collaboration is obviously new to me :) This experience has taught me a lot about it! Thanks!